# How to update a specific child in Retrofit 2 (Android)

Tags: android, retrofit2

How would I be able to update a specific child in `Retrofit2` when there are more than one data(s).

As you can see on the attached file, I have two data/passenger profile. I'd like to update the balance of the first passenger profile with the one that has **tagID: 613421**. How would that be possible?

[image]

```
public interface APIServicePassenger {

@GET("/passengers")
Call<List<Passenger>> getPassengers();

@PUT("/passengers")
Call<List<Passenger>> updatePassengerProfile(@Field("balance") int balance);
}
```

But I don't know how to use the *PUT request*

```
public class Config {

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://busartery.....";

public static Retrofit getClient() {
    Retrofit retrofit = null;

    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Config.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

I don't know if I'm doing the right thing.

```
if (!medtCustomerID.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() &&
                    !medtCustomerName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                balance += amountLoad;

                final Call<List<Passenger>> passengerCallList = servicePassenger.getPassengers();
                passengerCallList.enqueue(new Callback<List<Passenger>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<Passenger>> call, Response<List<Passenger>> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            List<Passenger> passengerList = response.body();

                            if (passengerList.size() != 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i <passengerList.size(); i++) {
                                    String name = passengerList.get(i).getName();
                                    if (name.equals(medtCustomerName.getText().toString().trim())) {
                                        //to update that specific data
                                        Passenger passenger = new Passenger(balance);

                                        Call<List<Passenger>> callPassList = servicePassenger.updatePassengerProfile(
                                                passenger.getBalance());
                                        callPassList.enqueue(new Callback<List<Passenger>>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onResponse(Call<List<Passenger>> call, Response<List<Passenger>> response) {
                                                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    Toast.makeText(LoaderActivity.this, "Successfully loaded.\n New Load " +balance, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onFailure(Call<List<Passenger>> call, Throwable t) {
                                                Toast.makeText(LoaderActivity.this, "onFailure(update): " +t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<Passenger>> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoaderActivity.this, "onFailure(btnLoad) :"+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: your question is not clear. explain more.

Comment: these data is coming from the `API` ?  @tin

Comment: show us your Retrofit interface

Comment: @ASh Ihope my questions already clear to you

Comment: @vishalyadav yes

Comment: @rustedbrain I already posted my Retrofit interface

Comment: if you know how to you post req then you know how to use PUT. both are same.

Comment: can you post `updatePassengerProfile` this `api method`

Comment: @Sagarnayak I'm sorry but it's confusing me. I just need someone that can help me.

Comment: pass the static value in balance `5` and check what respopnse is coming
`Call<List<Passenger>> callPassList = servicePassenger.updatePassengerProfile(5);` like this

Answer (score 0):

itsnt about your client code, but your server code.
REST allows you to update something using @PUT
The code you posted can't update only part of the node on the server. 
and the interface:

```
@PUT("/passengers")
Call<List<Passenger>> updatePassengerProfile(@Field("balance") int balance);
```

wont update it either because it won't know wich part of the list you are updating, u should provide it with a passenger ID

```
@PUT("/passengers")
Call<List<Passenger>> updatePassengerProfile(@Field("balance") int 
balance,@Field("id") String id);
```

ps and you ca probably loose the @Field annotation.

Again this willl work only if the server supports it